# How to import user libraries programmatically from a file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have "myUserLib.userlibraries" file with all the required user libraries defined. As part of my plug-in that i developed (this will create web projects and required settings), i want to import this file to the projects created by the plug-in.

Is there any programatic way to import libraries from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got this worked the way i want. I am now able to programmatically upload the userlibraries into workspace preferences from "myuserlibs.userlibraries" file. I used following eclipse plugins classes.

```
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.UserLibrary.class
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.UserLibraryManager.class
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.UserLibraryClasspathContainer.class
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.UserLibraryClasspathContainerInitializer.class
```

These classes have bunch of methods to achieve this task.

Once they got uploaded in to preferences, i am also able to programmatically add required user library entries into a respective projects (created by my plugin). Because i have around 8 web projects in my workspace and all of them required different set of user libraries in their classpath container.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a plugin to add these libraries to project classpath, I recommend that you consider writing a custom classpath container rather than re-using the user libraries facility. If you write a custom container, project classpath would include id of your container and JDT will query your code at runtime to get the actual list of classpath entries.

This will save you from having to store and maintain the contents of your library in workspace preferences, as you would have to do if you took the user library approach.

See org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathContainer class.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. I would need to just import my userlibraries programmatically same as the way we import via preferences. I dont need to add them in a classpath. Because, i have dozens of libraries defined my file, but not all the projects are going to use all of them. Once imported, i have second task where i need to add required library references to respective projects. I can use classpathContainer for my second part

Comment: I don't think you understand what classpath containers are. The Eclipse user library facility is just one type of classpath container that is based on library definition maintained in workspace preferences. I am suggesting that you implement your own as it would allow you to bypass the step of importing stuff into workspace metadata to get your plugin to work. A classpath container id is a path. The first segment is its type, but the rest is up to you. You can use the rest of the container path to tell you what "library" definition to lookup internally in your plugin logic.

Comment: I didn't know this. Thanks for your patience in explaining again. I thought these are two different things. If i can achieve this with IClasspathContainer, that would be great. I used classpath container to add individual .jar files in a classpath. I will do as you suggested and will reply back the result.

Comment: But i still have some doubts. I can add library reference in a classpath. How would i define a library. Because, one of my libraries (for eg. MYPROJECT_LIB) has 30 jars files defined, likewise there are more libraries. But i can only add library reference using classpath container, but what if there is no such lib defined. My question is, How can i create a library definition and add 30 jar references? I dont want ot create all the libraries and add jars one by one programatically. This is where i need help. all these defeined in a file and i need to simply import for defining libraries.

Comment: Your classpath container implementation can manager your list of jars however it is most convenient for the implementation. You can have a hardcodded list, you can read a file, etc. Your container just gets asked to provide the individual classpath entries. How you do that is up to you.